# why am i getting this Â£10 using charset=utf8

Tags: php, mysql, utf-8, character-encoding

If i enter a £ (UK Pound Symbol) into my DB why does it always add to the database with as Â£.

I thought this was down to the charset but thought utf8 should cure this

EDIT i am setting the charset as below

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host='.DBHOST.';dbname='.DBNAME.';charset=utf8', DBUSER, DBPASS);
```

any advice please.

Comment: Read this: http://stackoverflow.com/a/279279/1679849

Answer (score 0):

Use this before any other query

```
SET NAMES utf8;
```

Comment: $db->exec('SET NAMES utf8;')

Comment: Why has this been marked down? it WORKS perfectly! i have tried stackoverflow.com/a/279279/1679849 but am already doing everything it suggests (i think) but adding $db->exec('SET NAMES utf8;') to the INSERT query seems to have fixed the issue!